# NCurses adds new line when output greater than terminal columns

Tags: c, ncurses

I have noticed that when I print line in ncurses that takes more than number of terminal columns ncurses adds newline:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
        initscr();                      /* Start curses mode              */
        printw("Hello World aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!!!");
        refresh();                      /* Print it on to the real screen */
        getch();                        /* Wait for user input */
        endwin();                       /* End curses mode                */

        return 0;
}
```

Now as the terminal has less columns my output looks like this:

```
Hello World aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!!!
```

In my app I wan't to copy terminal output but when I do so I'm getting newline where line breaks but I didn't putted any new line when calling printw. Does ncurses add newlines automatically? How I can disable that? This is simple version of my problem as In my case I'm using mvwaddnwstr to print wide characters but problem stays.

Comment: What did you intend to happen? That some of your program output isn't seen? Suppose the output string is `Minutes left: 100` but it is too long and you only get to see `Minutes left: 1` ? Is that what you want?

Comment: I intend to see the same thing that happens with cat or vim, there is no new line appended.

Comment: Configure a wider terminal, if it isn't wide enough for the needs of your program.

Comment: I'm not following this suggestion can you come with an example?

Comment: In the terminal preferences. Or are you wanting [scroll bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617419/add-a-scrollbar-on-ncurses-or-make-it-like-more)?

Comment: And what problem does it solves? The example I have provided is just an example I want general solution when you don't know length of the line upfront.

Comment: Well if you want long lines to be extended like with a text editor, instead of wrapping to the next line, you need to implement scroll bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`printw`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html), [**`waddstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) (or [**`waddwstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html)) ultimately call [**`waddch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) (or [**`wadd_wch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wch.3x.html#h3-add_wch)), which wraps at the right margin.  You could use (but less convenient) [**`waddchstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html) or [**`wadd_wchstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html), which do not wrap.

Comment: wadd_wchstr takes more complex arguments but does the job